# When the variable goes up, the next time the loop runs it doesn't use the new variable number

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to find the first 100 of the p1*p2...*pn+1 sequence and then test if they are prime.

```
primes = [2,3]
def isItPrime(n):
  tests = primes.copy()
  while len(tests) != 0:
  if n % tests[-1] == 0:
    return False
  elif n % tests[-1] != 0:
    tests.pop()
    if len(tests) == 0:
      primes.append(n)
      return True
def firstNPrimes(n) :
   a = 4
   while len(primes) < n :
     isItPrime(a)
     a += 1
     print(primes)
def multiplyList(q) : 
   result = 1
   for x in q: 
   result = result * x  
   return result 
h = 1
while h < 100 :
   w = 2
   firstNPrimes(w)
   result = multiplyList(primes)
   float(result)
   result += 1
   print(result)
   w += 1
   print(w)
   h += 1
```

I don't get any errors but my code doesn't work. I think w either doesn't go up or it goes up and the program doesn't use it. When I print w after I make it go up, it goes up but the next time the program runs it doesn't use the new number.

Comment: your indent in the first while seems incorrect. So your if statement block following it won't execute. Likely leading to a syntax error. Likewise your for loop. Also, `primes` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: The sequence is p1 * p2...* pn?

Comment: Also where do you declare `primes`?

Comment: I defined primes as primes = [2,3] at the top of the code. Forgot to put it in here. Also the sequence is prime number* prime number*prime number + 1.

Comment: @Brik why did you de-select my answer? Anything wrong with the output?

Comment: @Ilragile so sorry accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the task, it is required to generated prime according to [the Euclid's proof of Euclid's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) from all primes between 2 and N and then print all generated primes for intervals where N goes from 2 to 100. I assume 100 is included, though it's not important.

Let's define a function **is_prime**(n) which return True or False. To check weather a number is prime you can check that the number is not divisible by any number from 2 to square root of the number. You might ask why square root? Because if A*B = N and if A is smaller than square root of N then B will be bigger then square root of N and we don't need to check B if we have already checked A. Let's use **ceil**(**sqrt**(N)) which returns the smallest integer value that is bigger than or equal to a number.

**get_prime_range**(n) generates all primes from 2 to n where n is included

**generate_prime**(primes) computes prime_1*prime_2* ... *prime_k + 1 which is also a prime number.

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def get_prime_range(n):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
    return primes

def generate_prime(primes):
    new_prime = 1 if primes else None
    for prime in primes:
        new_prime *= prime
    return new_prime + 1

for n in range(2, 101):
    print(generate_prime(get_prime_range(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with & adjusting your code, I think the following works:

```
def isItPrime(n):
  tests = primes.copy()
  while len(tests) != 0:
      if n % tests[-1] == 0:
        return False
      elif n % tests[-1] != 0:
        tests.pop()
        if len(tests) == 0:
          primes.append(n)
          return True

def firstNPrimes(n, a=5) :
   while len(primes) < n :
     isItPrime(a)
     a += 1

def multiplyList(q, result=1): 
   for x in q: 
     result *= x  
   return result

primes = [2,3] 
w, h, n_iter = 2, 1, 100

while h < n_iter :
   print("{}/{}".format(h,n_iter)) # To see progress
   firstNPrimes(w)
   result = multiplyList(primes)
   float(result)
   result += 1
   w += 1
   h += 1


print("Primes: {}".format(primes))
print("Product of the primes: {}".format(result))
```

Let me know if this is not what you expect.

Comment: Lastly note that you had firstNPrimes(n, a=4) originally which caused your code to loop endlessly. There were other things but this was the main problem.